# Symfony 2 debug toolbar not showing

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

The Symfony debug toolbar doesn't show up.

I am running the site on app_dev.php environment. The config_dev.yml file contains the following lines.

```yaml
web_profiler:
 toolbar: true
 intercept_redirects: false
```

app_dev/php doesn't have any IP restriction. It runs AppKernel with dev environment. Also, AppKernel contains the following line.

```php
$bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
```

The main problem could be the HTML markup, but it has both the opening and closing `<body>` tags. I even tried to remove all the HTML, and just leave it with few HTML tags, without luck.

Is there anything else I could try?
Maybe some files could be missing. How can I check it?

This is not a fresh Symfony installation.

Comment: Just in case, If you execute the `debug:router --env=dev` command, can you see all `_wdt` and `_profiler_*` routes ?

Comment: I get debug:router: command not found

Comment: Maybe try with `app/console router:debug --env=dev` (it's old name). What's the exact version of your Symfony install ?

Comment: Oh this one works. Yes there is a _wdt and _profiler routes alongside with many other.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you can tick all bullets in this checklist:

- You are using the dev mode by accessing the page via app_dev.php (True for you)
- The toolbar inserts itself in pages by looking for a terminating `</body>` tag on your generated page. If you don't have a `</body>` tag in your page the toolbar will not appear(as in the above answer). Example twig file as a reference:

  The line `{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}` will extend `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig` which injects default `<body>...</body>` into your custom twig files.

  ```
  {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

  {% block body %}
    Hello!
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- You have enabled the profiler in `AppKernel.php`

  ```
  public function registerBundles(){
    $bundles = ...
    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
      $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
    ...
    }
  return $bundles;
  }
  ```
- You have javascript enabled.
- Thoroughly Check recently added bundles(specially custom ones). Because [Cases like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038177/symfony-2-debug-toolbar-not-showing-breaks-html-in-dev-environment#answer-17039247) can cause the problem.

Comment: Yes, double checked everything. Deleted the whole HTML, left only your example with base.html.twig. 

I am accessing the page using: http://project.test/project.dev/public_html/app_dev.php

Comment: @The50 Did you check the latest case I just added? Don't you have any new bundle installed?

Comment: Yes, there is a few custom bundles, but the problem is that the site is not working at all without a few of them. But I got the idea, need to run the site without any custom bundles at all first.

Comment: Nice job @The50

Answer (score 8):

Double-check that your `<body>` tag has a closing `</body>` tag. In my experience, when the toolbar suddenly disappears it's because the closing body tag is missing due to malformed HTML, or because a controller is returning a `Response` object with just plain text content.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with a large(ish) application where the toolbar wasn't being shown on memory heavy pages. Turns out that my php memory limit was being exhausted. I set the `memory_limit` in my php.ini file to something that would be adequate and that sorted it.

Comment: Same here, it only happened on certain pages. I have twig files rendering lots of data. On app_dev.php It was too heavy and caused the toolbar error 'An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar.' So solution was to raise the "memory_limit" in the fpm ini file (in my case /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini)

Answer (score 1):

if you set the environment as dev it should display debug toolbar at the bottom

edit web/app.php as following;

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);

Answer (score 0):

I recently got an old project in SF3.4 and in my case the debug toolbar didn't show up because of the following keys in config.yml file

```
framework:
    [...]
    profiler:
        collect: false
```

I commented on those 2 lines and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall toolbar

```
composer remove profiler
composer require --dev profiler
```

Check the configuration

```
bin/console debug:config framework profiler
```