# Debugger does'nt display after update

Tags: debugging, toolbar, symfony4

I've a strange problem since yesterday, I've made an update of Symfony and since I don't have the debug toolbar anymore. It is displayed in my html code like this :

```html
<div id="sfwdtd14ed8" class="sf-toolbar sf-display-none" data-sfurl="/_wdt/d14ed8" style="display: none;">
```

Here is my web profiler config :

```yml
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

My config is good and I can display the debugger with url like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/_profiler/latest?ip=&limit=10
```

I can't find any solution if you could help me thank you.

Comment: Did you accidentally click the 'X' in the lower right-hand corner to close the toolbar? Bring the toolbar back by clicking he symfony logo in the same location.

Comment: Hi, no I don't have any logo and I did'nt click on the "X". I've made some tests and it's the same with a new project...

Comment: OK, sounds like you are in 'prod' mode rather than 'dev' mode. Check your `.env` file.

Comment: Thank you, I checked my .env and I'm in dev mode. I made other tests and it's very odd, when I create a symfony app from scratch with just the debug bar I have exactly the same problem. I just do a : 
-create-project;
-../composer.phar require --dev symfony/profiler-pack
When I start the server my background is blue and my toolbar is display:none...

Comment: Try this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650372/symfony-2-debug-toolbar-not-showing

Comment: No I check and adapt things with my Symfony 4 but I don't see anything wrong... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Symfony Client to latest version (4.5.1) resolved the issue, which was probably the "broken Symfony WDT", fixed in 4.4.5.